# Is it possible to do 3-sum/4-sum...k-sum better than O(n^2) with these conditions? - Tech Interview

Tags: arrays, algorithm

this is a classic problem, but I am curious if it is possible to do better with these conditions.

Problem: Suppose we have a sorted array of length 4*N, that is, each element is repeated 4 times. Note that N can be any natural number. Also, each element in the array is subject to the constraint 0 < A[i] < 190*N. Are there 4 elements in the array such that A[i] + A[j] + A[k] + A[m] = V, where V can be **any** positive integer; note we must use exactly 4 elements and they can be repeated. It is not necessarily a requirement to find the 4 elements that satisfy the condition, rather, just showing it can be done for a given array and V is enough.

Ex : A = [1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,11,11,11,11]
V = 22

This is true because, 11 + 5 + 5 + 1 = 22.

My attempt:

Instead of "4sum" I first tried k-sum, but this proved pretty difficult so I instead went for this variation. The first solution I came to was rather naive O(n^2). However, given these constraints, I imagine that we can do better. I tried some dynamic programming methods and divide and conquer, but that didn't quite get me anywhere. To be specific, I am not sure how to cleverly approach this in a way where I can "eliminate" portions of the array without having to explicitly check values against all or almost all permutations.

Comment: You could build all the sums of unique pairs O(n^2/16) which is still O(n^2) but a factor of 1/16 is still quite some difference. Then use two pointers and traverse the sums of pairs to build 4sums, no additional checks required because each number exists four times O(n^2/8). Combined it is O(n^2/16 + n^2/8) = O(n^2).

Comment: Thats true! But I was looking for a solution that would be better than O(n^2).  Perhaps O(n*V) but im not certain.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make an vector **S0** of length **256N** where **S0[x]=1** if **x** appears in **A**.
2. Perform a convolution of **S0** with itself to produce a new vector **S1** of length **512N**.  **S1[x]** is nonzero iff **x** is the sum of 2 numbers in **A**.
3. Perform a convolution of **S1** with itself to make a new vector **S2**.  **S2[x]** is nonzero iff **x** is the sum of 4 numbers in **A**.
4. Check **S2[V]** to get your answer.

Convolution can be performed in **O(N log N)** time using FFT convolution (http://www.dspguide.com/ch18/2.htm) or similar techniques.

Since at most 4 such convolutions are performed, the total complexity is **O(N log N)**

Comment: Great. After doing a little research on FFT convolution, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.